# Excel is closing unexpectedly when closing C# WinForms App called in a DLL

Tags: c#, winforms, vba, dll, interop

I have a C# Winforms-Application. I have set the Output Type of the Project to 'Class Library' and made it COM visible so I can reference it in my VBA Code in Excel. Hence I can start my WinForms-App through Excel.

Everything works fine so far. In my VBA Code I'm calling the Application like this (Macro):

```
Dim app As MyWinFormsApp.Program
Set app = New MyWinFormsApp.Program
Dim result As Integer
result = app.Main()
```

My Program Class in my C#-Code looks like this:

```
public int Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        return 0;
    }
```

When I start my Macro the WinForms Window opens and and the program works fine.

My Problem is: When I'm closing the WinForms Window by clicking on the red X, Excel also closes unexpectedly.

What I've already found out is:

In my C# Class Form1.Designer.cs I have this Dispose-Method:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

When I call the base.Dispose()-Method passing 'false'

```
base.Dispose(false);
```

Excel is not closing unexpectedly when I close the WinForms-Window, but when I want to close Excel afterwards, it's not possible. I get this 'Mouse-Wait-Symbol' and can't do anything so I have to kill the Excel-Process in TaskManager.

(I've also tried using a new WinForms-Project that really does nothing to provide that in my original project I'm doing something wrong... I had exactly the same behaviour.)

So my question is: **Does anyone know how I can close my WinForms-App and afterwards close Excel in a 'normal way'.**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the Application.UserControl Property to true, before closing the winform.

"When the UserControl property is False for an object, that object is released when the last programmatic reference to the object is released. If this property is False, Microsoft Excel quits when the last object in the session is released."
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff841219.aspx

Comment: Not sure wether I understood you right. I simply set Application.UserControl = True in my VBA Code before calling my app.Main() Method. Got the same result.. Excel is closing unexpectedly...

Comment: I can't test right now, but I was saying to set in your Main() method, instead of in the vba code. Maybe the program is modifying it when it runs, idk ...

Answer (score 0):

the Problem is the using of Application.Run().
If you are calling a form from VBA you should use frm.show().

Then it will work like a charm.
Example in c#:

```
        public void InitializeForm()
    {
        Form1 Form = new Form1();
        Form.Show();
    }
```

Example in VBA:

```
Sub OpenForm()
Dim CallForm As New CallAndInitialize
CallForm.InitializeForm End Sub
```